# Object orientation in Go - Struct/Composition/ Encapsulation

Tags: json, oop, struct, go, composition

I have two .go files - client.go ( contains the main fund) and logic.go. One of them contains the function which needs to be executed when it is invoked from the client.
{

```
client.go -

package main

func main() {
  // url is the url of the server to which the REST call has to be sent to fetch the response
  client := NewClient(url)
  client.DummyFunc()

}

logic.go

import (
"fmt"
)

func DummyFunc(){

   // Logic here which returns the json response
}
```

}

I am trying to understand what could be a good object oriented way in Go to do this. Since Go has its own style of object inheritance/composition/encapsulation, could you please suggest me a way to do this as I am new to this language.

Also, I want the main function in my client.go and logic.go should contain other utility functions which can be invoked from my client.go file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before addressing the OO way of doing this, does `client.go` need to hold the `main` function? Does `logic.go` need to be separated from `client.go`? Also, `logic.go` must be part of a package. I'm having a hard time picking up what was left out for brevity versus what may be missing.

How I would do things:

main.go (would be the same for both cases)

```
package main

import "client"

func main() {
    client := client.Client { ClientUrl: url } // This takes the place of NewClient(url)
    client.DummyFunc()
}
```

client.go

```
package client

type Client struct {
    ClientUrl      string
}

func (c Client) DummyFunc() {
    // Logic here which returns the JSON response
}
```

If you would like to keep `logic` separate from `client`, you could do this.

client.go

```
package client

type Client struct {
    ClientUrl      string
    Logic          // An anonymous field let's you call Logic functions 
}
```

logic.go

```
package client

type Logic struct {
    // Fields
}

func (l Logic) DummyFunc() {
    // Logic here which returns the JSON response
}
```

Notice, since we kept `Logic` anonymous in the `Client` struct, we were able to call `DummyFunc`.

You can see some more examples here: http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/inheritance-and-subclassing-in-go-or.html

EDIT --------------------------------------------------------

It's a little awkward, but here's `client.go` with main function in it and `logic.go` is separate. If you add more functions in `logic`, then `client` will be able to call all other functions.

client.go

```
package main

import "logic"

type Client struct {
    ClientUrl      string
    logic.Logic
}

func main() {
    client := client.Client { ClientUrl: url } // This takes the place of NewClient(url)
    client.DummyFunc()
}
```

logic.go

```
package logic

import "fmt"

type Logic struct {
    // Fields
}

func (l Logic) DummyFunc() {
    fmt.Printf("In DummyFunc\n")
}
```

With that being said, I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. If `logic` doesn't have any fields, then it makes no sense to have it as a separate struct. I would make it a function of `client`, as I pointed out in the first case in the original post.

Comment: You are right. I want the main func() only in my client.go file and the other function implementations in logic.go which I should be able to invoke from my client.go by passing in the URL parameter.

Comment: Alright. Is it clear the changes you would need to make to combine `client` and `main`? Much of it would be the same, just moving some code around.

Comment: so the main fund() is in the client.go file which when ran should invoke the function in the logic.go file by passing in the URL. That's the whole intention here. I appreciate your efforts though if you could also provide your way of doing it, it'll be great. Thanks !

Comment: Edited. There's enough code there now you should be able to manipulate to your needs.